# Charles Proxy SSL Certificate not downloading on Mac

Tags: charles-proxy

I am getting "< unknown > " requests that I can't read in the Charles proxy, when I enable SSL, they don't load at all.

I think my issue is that I dont have the certificate installed, when I go through Charles > SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate or through chls.pro/ssl. It will open Keychain Access but won't prompt for any install and I don't see it coming up on my list of keychains - see below
[charles screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5TSI.jpg)

[keychain access screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSJsQ.jpg)

Comment: I'm also having trouble getting Charles root cert to work in MacOS 13.2. It used to work fine.

Comment: Same in MacOS 13.1

Answer (score 6):

I had to add one more step for me to work:

1. If the Charles is SSL Proxying, stop it!!!  Proxy -> Stop SSL Proxying
2. Help -> SSL Proxying -> Reset Charles Root Certificate
3. Help -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles Root Certificate

Comment: Not sure why there is no upvotes on this. This actually worked . 

Saved me in 2022 , 2023 ..and i might come in 2024 again :)

Comment: this one works . Magic is with  Reset Charles Root Certificate. So this works out of all the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on MacOS 13.2.1 because I deleted the cert and when I tried to re-add the cert (Charles -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles Root Certificate) it would never appear in keychain.

I tried re-installing Charles and rebooting my computer, but neither fixed the issue.

What I found that worked for me was deleting Charles AND the Application Support Cache for Charles. Here were my steps:

1. Delete your Charles app from Applications
2. Open Finder
3. Click "Go"
4. Click "Go to Folder"
5. Paste in "~/Library/Application Support" (Note: This is folder in your home directory not root)
6. Look for the "Charles" directory and delete it. (I made a backup copy just in case)
7. Reinstall Charles
8. Then install the cert (Charles -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles Root Certificate). It should now hopefully show up in keychain for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on MacOS 13.3, I delete and re-install the Charles, it still can't install the root cert.

```
1. If the Charles is SSL Proxying, stop it!!!  Proxy -> Stop SSL Proxying
2. Help -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles Root Certificate,
```

it works.